# Installing Problem

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, grub-legacy

Today I installed a fresh and clean windows 8.1 pro in legacy mode and the problem is when I am trying to install Ubuntu latest version (14.04) or any other version of Ubuntu, I get an option **u have no other operating system or installed windows on your system**.

While on other side I have windows 8.1.  Then how to install Ubuntu with my current OS windows 8.1 pro. Problem is I'm not getting the option of installing option with windows 8.1 (along side option ).Ii m using sony vaio svf1521ksnw . and I already disable the secure boot and also turn off the fast start up.

Comment: See this question about trying an installation using manual partitioning: http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Is your Windows partition encrypted? I've had similar issues with encrypted filesystems